# Ajuda com a função onchange

Tags: javascript, html

Estou tentando usar a função `onchange`, até consigo pegar o valor, mas não consigo fazer uso do valor obtido, Segue o código:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <select id="mySelect" onchange="myFunction()">
    <option value="1">1 Questão
    <option value="2">2 Questões
    <option value="3">3 Questões
    <option value="4">4 Questões
  </select>
</div>
<b id="demo"></b> <!--aqui eu imprimo o valor de x corretamente-->
```

Gostaria de usar o valor de `X` como complemento ao endereço da imagem

tentei assim:

```
  <img src="img/gab<?echo '<b id="demo"></b>'?>.png" />
```

Assim

```
  <img src="img/gab<script>x</script>.png" />
```

e

```
  <img src="img/gab<script>$x</script>.png" />
```

Não sei como fazer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tente fazer dessa forma:

```js
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
    document.getElementById("imagem").src = "img/gab" + x + ".png"
}
```

```html
<select id="mySelect" onchange="myFunction()">
  <option value="1">1 Questão
  <option value="2">2 Questões
  <option value="3">3 Questões
  <option value="4">4 Questões
</select>

<b id="demo"></b>

<img id="imagem">
```